# 12 bit asyncronous USART using pic (rx)

Tags: pic, uart, embedded, microchip, serial-bus

I need to implement an asynchronous receiver USART. The length of the frame is 12 bits.

I looked into implementing this with a pic 16F1455 but it only supports 8-9 bits: "Programmable 8-bit or 9-bit character length".

Question: Is there any simple way on how to do this?
I tried bit banging the data, but my timer is not accurate enough.

Comment: Why do you think your timer is not accurate enough?

Comment: A software solution should be possible at reasonably low baud rates. For higher baudrates I think you'll be out of luck quickly on this CPU, unless you can perhaps change the frame size to standard frames of 8-bits.

Comment: This sounds like an X-Y problem. Why do you need to support 12-bit frames in the first place? But in any case, an interrupt-driven software solution should be straightforward. Use interrupt-on-change to detect the leading edge of the start bit, and use a timer interrupt to sample any number of data bits after that.

Comment: my timer is not accurate enough: sometimes output pulses are not same length , probably because other tasks are taking too long ...

i cant change the lenght of my frame :( it must be 12 bit long)

Comment: i also have an usb interrupt running.... it seems its conficting with the timer

Comment: Are you confusing a 12 bit frame requirement with needing to transfer 12 bits?